# Having problems aligning Twitter & Facebook button horizontally and not getting a Twitter count.

Tags: html

I need help please I am using the following code to insert Twitter & Facebook buttons on a webpage. I am a **novice** on HTML; I cannot seem to align the buttons right and horizontal. I’m using shoppingcartplus as a host sit for the website. I've generated the code from twitter and facebook sites.

In addition when I tweet the counter is not incremented.

```
<!-- ======> (Start of Facebook button code after  body tag, no body tag in code)  -->
<div id="fb-root">
    &nbsp;</div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- ======> (End of Facebook button code after  body tag, no body tag in code)  -->

<!-- ======> (Start of twitter button code)  -->
<p align=right>
<p> <a class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.afrikongo.com" href="https://twitter.com/share">Tweet</a> <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</p>

<!-- ======> (End of twitter button code)  -->

<!-- ======> (Start of Facebook button code button placement on site)  -->

<p align=right> <div class="fb-like" data-font="arial" data-    href="http://www.afrikongo.com" data-layout="button_count" data-send="true" data-show-faces="true" data-width="450">
    &nbsp; </div>
</p>
<!-- ======> (End of Facebook button code button placement on site)  -->
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/roctimo/GEyXf/1/

All I did was make sure the two share buttons were both contained in div's, put them in a container, and styled the div's in the container so that they float right and next to each other, with some margin for spacing.

The CSS:

```
.share_buttons > div {
    float:right;   
    margin:0 0 0 20px;    
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="share_buttons">
    <div>
        <a class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.afrikongo.com" href="https://twitter.com/share">Tweet</a> <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
    </div>

    <div class="fb-like" data-font="arial" data-href="http://www.afrikongo.com" data-layout="button_count" data-send="true" data-show-faces="true" data-width="450">
        &nbsp; 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback I really appreciated it, I have not used HTML in years, and consider myself a NOVICE at this point. I am a little Familiar with CSS. I have tried your suggestion and it still does not work. I have been searching all over the net for solutions and their seems to be a number of people with the same problem. The alignment problem still remains.

Comment: It should work just fine if you're using the CSS and adjusting your structure correctly.  It works on the JSFiddle link.

Comment: Can you force the Facebook comment box not to overflow to the right? Error behavior example [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28076956/fb_comment_overflow.png)

Comment: @Saran Yes You can achieve that applying this code to the share_button <div> : .share_buttons{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}